# How to Let Recordset #2 in the Same Position as the Similar Recordset#1

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

I'm working with 2 recordsets: #1 and #2. recordset #1 is the form recordset, which is NOT DataUpdatable because its source is a query with non editable fields. recordset #2 is DataUpdatable because its source is a table. recordset #2 table is the recordset #1 table source.

every time I save the form's controls values, I change the recordset status to Add/Edit, paste each value in its respective recordset field and upadte the recordset. the problem is that I have to do it in the recordset #2 because #1 is not editable. what I need is to move recordset #2 position to the same #1 position before I paste the control values. I'm trying to use the recordset #1 bookmark in recordset #2, since they have the same table structure, total of fields, etc... but it says that the bookmark is not valid.

both recordsets are in the same order, both SQL sources have "ORDER BY" clause. for AddNew mode there's no problem because the recordset position is a new one, don't need to find it. the problem is for EditInProgress mode  because I have to match both positions so I can update the form's control values addressed to recordset #1 fields into the equivalent recordset #2 fields.

thanks in advance.

hi, AVG. this is the encrypt/decrypt code:

```
Public Function EncriptarDecriptarTexto(textoNormal As Variant) As Variant
    On Error GoTo ErroGeral
    Dim posicaoLetraEncript As Integer
    Dim valorLetraEncript As Integer
    Dim tamanhoTextoNormal As Integer
    Dim tamanhoTextoEncript As Integer
    Dim textoEncript As String
    Dim i As Integer

    If ((textoNormal & "") = "") Then
        GoTo ErroGeral
    End If

    tamanhoTextoNormal = Len(textoNormal)
    tamanhoTextoEncript = Len(textoEncript)
    posicaoLetraEncript = 0
    textoEncript = "Any text you want"

    For i = 1 To tamanhoTextoNormal
        posicaoLetraEncript = posicaoLetraEncript + 1

        If posicaoLetraEncript > tamanhoTextoEncript Then
            posicaoLetraEncript = 1
        End If

        valorLetraEncript = Asc(Mid(textoEncript, posicaoLetraEncript, 1))
        Mid(textoNormal, i, 1) = Chr(Asc(Mid(textoNormal, i, 1)) Xor valorLetraEncript)
    Next i

    EncriptarDecriptarTexto = textoNormal

Sair:
    Exit Function
ErroGeral:
    EncriptarDecriptarTexto = Null
    GoTo Sair
End Function
```

about the table update: I'm now updating through INSERT/UPDATE statements.

Comment: AVG is right. Correct the design. Non-editable fields don't stop anything as you wouldn't update these anyway. If you aggregated values, pull these from an outer join.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like poor design to start with. That said, instead of opening a second recordset and trying to synchronize with the form's recordsource, simply use an update statement. `Update <YourTable> SET <field1> = <NewValue1>, <field2> = <NewValue2> WHERE <PK>=<CurrentRecordPK>`

Comment: I encrypt the data before saving in the tables and I use a function in the form's query source for decrypting this data and feed the bound controls. That's why the form's recordset is not editable. I can contour this situation by using .FindFirst method but I want to use .Bookmark somehow, though it is incompatible in this case.

Comment: A bookmark won't work because the recordsets are different, period. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff823084.aspx. What is wrong with using an update statement like I proposed?

Comment: Ok AVG, I understood your code and it is clever. What I want is to avoid using the WHERE clause because my code is generic and it works fine for any kind of table structure - the same code saves any kind of recordset. Now, if I use WHERE clause, my code will lose the property of being generic.

Comment: Thor, What you are trying to do is very inefficient. You are opening up another recordset containing all of the records in the recordsource of the form, dragging all of those records across the network (assuming you are on a network), simply to update a single record. It may seem cool, but simply doesn't make sense. A simple update statement doesn't need to be so generic.

Comment: AVG, my code is generic. it is quite efficient. it's been working fine for any kind of table structure so far. you tell me an efficient way to save encrypted text from the form controls into tables and vice versa keeping the generic property.

Comment: Thor, I don't think anyone can without seeing you code. How about posting it so someone can offer a suggestion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78689/discussion-between-thor-my-and-avg).

Comment: AVG, your suggestion simply doesn't work because Update statement doesn't "update" the recordset EditMode, it still keeps as EditAdd or EditInProgress. this is quite inefficiente and troublesome to have to change the recordset status by other means if not by the regular course when changes really happen. thanks anyway.